# Составление всех вариантов перебора массива массивов

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив variants, каждый элемент которого содержит массив directions с 1 элементом, его ключом является порядковый номер элемента directions в выходном массиве, который нужно составить.

```
[variants] => Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [directions] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [IterationNumber] => 0
                    )
            )
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [directions] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [IterationNumber] => 1
                    )
            )
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [directions] => Array
            (
                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [IterationNumber] => 2
                    )
            )
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [directions] => Array
            (
                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [IterationNumber] => 3
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

Максимальное значение ключа элемента directions может быть больше 1. Но входной массив всегда содержит все элементы directions от 0 до N.

Необходимо составить новый массив variants, содержащий полный перебор всех возможных вариантов перестановки элементов directions от 0 до N.

```
[variants] => Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [directions] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [IterationNumber] => 0
                    )
                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [IterationNumber] => 2
                    )
            )
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [directions] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [IterationNumber] => 0
                    )
                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [IterationNumber] => 3
                    )
            )
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [directions] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [IterationNumber] => 1
                    )
                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [IterationNumber] => 2
                    )
            )

    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [directions] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [IterationNumber] => 1
                    )
                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [IterationNumber] => 3
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

Прошу помощи в решении этой проблемы или подсказок к решению.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Упрощенный алгоритм составления вариантов перебора массива массивов:

//Исходный массив

```
    $a = [
        0 => [
            0 => 'a',
            1 => 'b',
            2 => 'c'
        ],
        1 => [
            0 => 'd',
            1 => 'e',
            2 => 'f',
            3 => 'g',
        ],
        2 => [
            0 => 'h',
            1 => 'k'
        ],
        3 => [
            0 => 'j',
            1 => 'l'
        ],
    ];
```

//скрипт для составления вариантов переборов

```
    $reverse = array_reverse($a, true);
    $result = [];
    if (count($reverse) > 1) {
        foreach ($reverse as $rk => $rv) {
            if (isset($reverse[$rk - 1])) {
                $prev = $reverse[$rk - 1];
                foreach ($prev as $parentKey => $parentVal) {
                    if (isset($result[$rk])) {
                        $result[$rk - 1][$parentVal] = $result[$rk];
                    } else {
                        $result[$rk - 1][$parentVal] = $rv;
                    }
                }
                if (isset($result[$rk])) unset($result[$rk]);
            }
        }
        $result = $result[0];
    } else {
        $reverse = $reverse[0];
        foreach ($reverse as $rk => $rv) {
            $result[] = $rv;
        }
    }

    $itog = array();
    $variant = array();
    $iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveArrayIterator($result), \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    foreach ($iterator as $key => $item) {
        if (is_array($item)) {
            $variant[] = $key;
        } else {
            $variant[] = $item;

            if (!isset($oldVariant)) {
                $oldVariant = $variant;
            }

            $oldCount = count($oldVariant);
            $curCount = count($variant);

            foreach ($variant as $k => $v) {
                $oldVariant[$oldCount - $curCount + $k] = $variant[$k];
            }
            $itog[] = $oldVariant;

            $variant = array();
        }
    }

    echo '<pre>'."\r\n\r\n";
    print_r($itog);
    echo '</pre>';
```

//результат выполнения скрипта

```
    $itog = Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
        [1] => d
        [2] => h
        [3] => j
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
        [1] => d
        [2] => h
        [3] => l
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
        [1] => d
        [2] => k
        [3] => j
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
        [1] => d
        [2] => k
        [3] => l
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
        [1] => e
        [2] => h
        [3] => j
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
        [1] => e
        [2] => h
        [3] => l
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
        [1] => e
        [2] => k
        [3] => j
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
        [1] => e
        [2] => k
        [3] => l
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
        [1] => f
        [2] => h
        [3] => j
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
        [1] => f
        [2] => h
        [3] => l
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
        [1] => f
        [2] => k
        [3] => j
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
        [1] => f
        [2] => k
        [3] => l
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
        [1] => g
        [2] => h
        [3] => j
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
        [1] => g
        [2] => h
        [3] => l
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
        [1] => g
        [2] => k
        [3] => j
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
        [1] => g
        [2] => k
        [3] => l
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [0] => b
        [1] => d
        [2] => h
        [3] => j
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [0] => b
        [1] => d
        [2] => h
        [3] => l
    )

[18] => Array
    (
        [0] => b
        [1] => d
        [2] => k
        [3] => j
    )

[19] => Array
    (
        [0] => b
        [1] => d
        [2] => k
        [3] => l
    )

[20] => Array
    (
        [0] => b
        [1] => e
        [2] => h
        [3] => j
    )

[21] => Array
    (
        [0] => b
        [1] => e
        [2] => h
        [3] => l
    )

[22] => Array
    (
        [0] => b
        [1] => e
        [2] => k
        [3] => j
    )

[23] => Array
    (
        [0] => b
        [1] => e
        [2] => k
        [3] => l
    )

[24] => Array
    (
        [0] => b
        [1] => f
        [2] => h
        [3] => j
    )

[25] => Array
    (
        [0] => b
        [1] => f
        [2] => h
        [3] => l
    )

[26] => Array
    (
        [0] => b
        [1] => f
        [2] => k
        [3] => j
    )

[27] => Array
    (
        [0] => b
        [1] => f
        [2] => k
        [3] => l
    )

[28] => Array
    (
        [0] => b
        [1] => g
        [2] => h
        [3] => j
    )

[29] => Array
    (
        [0] => b
        [1] => g
        [2] => h
        [3] => l
    )

[30] => Array
    (
        [0] => b
        [1] => g
        [2] => k
        [3] => j
    )

[31] => Array
    (
        [0] => b
        [1] => g
        [2] => k
        [3] => l
    )

[32] => Array
    (
        [0] => c
        [1] => d
        [2] => h
        [3] => j
    )

[33] => Array
    (
        [0] => c
        [1] => d
        [2] => h
        [3] => l
    )

[34] => Array
    (
        [0] => c
        [1] => d
        [2] => k
        [3] => j
    )

[35] => Array
    (
        [0] => c
        [1] => d
        [2] => k
        [3] => l
    )

[36] => Array
    (
        [0] => c
        [1] => e
        [2] => h
        [3] => j
    )

[37] => Array
    (
        [0] => c
        [1] => e
        [2] => h
        [3] => l
    )

[38] => Array
    (
        [0] => c
        [1] => e
        [2] => k
        [3] => j
    )

[39] => Array
    (
        [0] => c
        [1] => e
        [2] => k
        [3] => l
    )

[40] => Array
    (
        [0] => c
        [1] => f
        [2] => h
        [3] => j
    )

[41] => Array
    (
        [0] => c
        [1] => f
        [2] => h
        [3] => l
    )

[42] => Array
    (
        [0] => c
        [1] => f
        [2] => k
        [3] => j
    )

[43] => Array
    (
        [0] => c
        [1] => f
        [2] => k
        [3] => l
    )

[44] => Array
    (
        [0] => c
        [1] => g
        [2] => h
        [3] => j
    )

[45] => Array
    (
        [0] => c
        [1] => g
        [2] => h
        [3] => l
    )

[46] => Array
    (
        [0] => c
        [1] => g
        [2] => k
        [3] => j
    )

[47] => Array
    (
        [0] => c
        [1] => g
        [2] => k
        [3] => l
    )

);
```